# Resolve this DIV issue

Tags: html

It seems that I have no missing DIVs or at least I see it. It seems to be off and overlap Any suggestions? I am unable to see the problems. The top and bottom one works well but the one with the Build Release notes and Supplemental Release Notes are off quite a bit.

```
  <h2 class="Billboard">
            <a href="#">System Knowledge Base</a></h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p align="center">
                    <a href="../customercare.aspx">Home</a> I <a href="../customercare.aspx">Customer Care</a> 
                    I <a href="../fieldcustomercare.aspx">Field Customer Care</a> 
                    I <a href="../Logout.aspx"> Logout </a>
                </p>
        </div>

<h2 class="Billboard">
            General System Information</h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                80 Links and Documents
            </p>
        </div>

        **<h2 class="QuickLinks">
            Build Release Notes</h2>
        <div class="QuickLinks">
                <p>
             120 Links and Documents
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="QuickLinks">
            Supplemental Release Notes</h2>
      <div style="float:right">
                <p>
10 Link and Documents
                </p>
             </div>**


        <h2 class="Billboard">
            TFACTS Customer Care</h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                10 Link and Documents
            </p>
        </div>
        <h2 class="Billboard">
            Reference Materials and Storyboards
        </h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                250 Links and documents
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    </div>

    <!-- CLOSES THE MAIN CONTENT DIV -->
```

Comment: Do you have any CSS to go with this HTML?  It's going to be hard to spot where the divs overlap without the styles.

Comment: Are we talking about a problem with code or layout?  You'll find code problems are much easier to spot if you format your code carefully, indenting each line.  Errors in paired tags are far easier to spot this way.

Answer (score 0):

You do in fact close a `<DIV>` prematurely. See the line below that I've commented out.

```
  <h2 class="Billboard">
            <a href="#">System Knowledge Base</a></h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p align="center">
                    <a href="../customercare.aspx">Home</a> I <a href="../customercare.aspx">Customer Care</a> 
                    I <a href="../fieldcustomercare.aspx">Field Customer Care</a> 
                    I <a href="../Logout.aspx"> Logout </a>
                </p>
        </div>

<h2 class="Billboard">
            General System Information</h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                80 Links and Documents
            </p>
        </div>

        **<h2 class="QuickLinks">
            Build Release Notes</h2>
        <div class="QuickLinks">
                <p>
             120 Links and Documents
                </p>
        <!--- **   </div> RIGHT HERE ** --->
        </div>
        <h2 class="QuickLinks">
            Supplemental Release Notes</h2>
      <div style="float:right">
                <p>
10 Link and Documents
                </p>
             </div>**


        <h2 class="Billboard">
            TFACTS Customer Care</h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                10 Link and Documents
            </p>
        </div>
        <h2 class="Billboard">
            Reference Materials and Storyboards
        </h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                250 Links and documents
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    </div>

    <!-- CLOSES THE MAIN CONTENT DIV -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an extra closing div tag. I am going to mark this question on hold because it is too localized. Please use the W3C Validator for things like this: http://validator.w3.org/check

See the closed div tag below marked with a comment:

```
     <h2 class="Billboard">
            <a href="#">System Knowledge Base</a></h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p align="center">
                    <a href="../customercare.aspx">Home</a> I <a href="../customercare.aspx">Customer Care</a> 
                    I <a href="../fieldcustomercare.aspx">Field Customer Care</a> 
                    I <a href="../Logout.aspx"> Logout </a>
                </p>
        </div>

<h2 class="Billboard">
            General System Information</h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                80 Links and Documents
            </p>
        </div>

        **<h2 class="QuickLinks">
            Build Release Notes</h2>
        <div class="QuickLinks">
                <p>
             120 Links and Documents
                </p>
            </div> <!-- EXTRA CLOSING TAG IS HERE -->
        </div>
        <h2 class="QuickLinks">
            Supplemental Release Notes</h2>
      <div style="float:right">
                <p>
10 Link and Documents
                </p>
             </div>**


        <h2 class="Billboard">
            TFACTS Customer Care</h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                10 Link and Documents
            </p>
        </div>
        <h2 class="Billboard">
            Reference Materials and Storyboards
        </h2>
        <div class="Billboard">
            <p>
                250 Links and documents
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    </div>

    <!-- CLOSES THE MAIN CONTENT DIV -->
```

Comment: There's another extra `</div>` at the very end.